# Can't create children in custom content collection with structure tree

Tags: typoscript, neoscms

I've defined a custom document node `Project` which has a child node `gallery` (just a content collection for images):

```
'Vendor.Website:Project':
  superTypes: ['TYPO3.Neos:Document']
  childNodes:
    gallery:
      type: 'TYPO3.Neos:ContentCollection'
      constraints:
        nodeTypes:
          'TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes:Image': TRUE
          '*': FALSE
```

The corresponding TypoScript is:

```
prototype(TYPO3.Neos:PrimaryContent).project {
    condition = ${q(documentNode).is('[instanceof Vendor.Website:Project]')}
    type = 'Vendor.Website:Project'
}

prototype(Vendor.Website:Project) < prototype(TYPO3.Neos:Content) {
    node = ${node}

    gallery = TYPO3.Neos:ContentCollection {
        nodePath = 'gallery'
    }
}
```

And the corresponding template is:

```
{namespace neos=TYPO3\Neos\ViewHelpers}
{namespace flow=TYPO3\Flow\ViewHelpers}
{namespace ts=TYPO3\TypoScript\ViewHelpers}
<article>
    <ts:render path="gallery" />
</article>
```

But as long as the content collection `gallery` is not named `main` I'm only able to add images into the `gallery` by using the content canvas but not the structure tree button `create new` which is disabled. Does anybody know why?

**Update**

I also tried it with an alternative page renderer like suggested in the comments:

```
project < page
project {
    body {
        templatePath = 'resource://Vendor.Website/Private/Templates/Page/Project.html'

        content {
            main >
            gallery = PrimaryContent
            gallery {
                nodePath = 'gallery'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For that I also have updated the node type definition:

```
'Vendor.Website:Project':
  superTypes: ['TYPO3.Neos:Document']
  childNodes:
    gallery:
      type: 'TYPO3.Neos:ContentCollection'
      constraints:
        nodeTypes:
          'TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes:Image': TRUE
          '*': FALSE
  properties:
    'layout':
      type: string
      defaultValue: 'project'
```

And at least the `project` template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{namespace neos=TYPO3\Neos\ViewHelpers}
{namespace flow=TYPO3\Flow\ViewHelpers}
{namespace ts=TYPO3\TypoScript\ViewHelpers}
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<f:section name="body">
    <main>
        {content.gallery -> f:format.raw()}
    </main>
</f:section>
</body>
</html>
```

But with the same result.

Comment: Will try to reproduce. Sounds like some mapping issue.

Comment: Ok, we discussed that on IRC. @witrin please try my recommended solution to use an alternative page renderer. I can otherwise try to come up with an example...